# Django DB index is present or not

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have a model and `db_index=True`, so 1 migration file is created. Due to some reason I have Deleted the index directly in DB with PgAdmin. And also removed the `db_index=True` from model. Again it will try to apply migration with

```
  operations = [
            migrations.RemoveIndex(
                model_name='Person',
                name='name_idx',
            ),
```

So if i run this on my machine(where i have deleted the index) will raise error `ValueError("No index named %s on model %s" % (name, self.name))`. Is there any way that I can do Delete index only if it is present.

Comment: Are there other operations in this migration?

Comment: migrate back then reapply the migrations. I would suggest not to remove stuff via pgAdmin or sql raw scripts. `./manage.py migrate appName 0012` where "0012" is the migration where everything was ok. then delete the skipped files and just migrate again.

Comment: No there is no other migration or changes

Comment: Yes I agree. I can unapply the migration and it will work. But there is a complexity involved. The changes were made on server and I don't have access to it anymore. I can get the access but I wanted to have a way around.